# My command is not setting my role id when I run it, it never SETS it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a mute command, but when trying to set the ROLE ID for my database, it won't set it, does anybody know how to fix this?

What I am using: `discord.js`, `quick.db`

Different files are between THREE line of comments, and a large amount of spaces.

```js
// Setmute.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'setmute',
    description: 'Mutes a user.',
    aliases: ['setmuterole', 'muterole'],
    usage: 'mention reason',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args, user) {
        const db = require('quick.db');
        let member = message.guild.member(message.member);
        if (message.mentions.channels.first()) {
            if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) {
                db.set(`${member.guild.id}-muterole`, message.mentions.roles.first().id);
                console.log(message.mentions.roles.first());
            } else if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) {
                return message.reply('you must have \"Manage Guild\" permmissions to access this command, sorry!');
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```js
// printmute.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'printmute',
    description: 'Mutes a user.',
    aliases: ['printmuterole'],
    usage: 'mention reason',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args, user) {
        const db = require('quick.db');
        let member = message.guild.member(message.member);
        let role = db.get(`${member.guild.id}-muterole`);

        if (!role) return message.reply("You never set a role.");

        console.log(role);
    }
}
```

```js
// Index.js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const db = require('quick.db');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {

    let member = message.guild.member(message.member);

    let prefix = db.get(`${member.guild.id}-prefix`); 

    if (!prefix) prefix = '?';

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

When I run the `setmute` command(of course, mentioning a role), then I run my `printmute` it says "You never set a role.", which is said when the guild doesn't have a role set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick.db data is stored in a file named `json.sqlite`. When you use `require("quick.db");` and you use `set()`, `get()` or any QuickDB's method, it will create a `json.sqlite` file in the current folder (or load it if it's already created). I think

You need to require QuickDB one time in your `index.js` file and to add a `db` property to one of your variables like `client`. Then you will be able to use `client.db.set()` and `client.db.get()` without use require each time you want to use quick.db.

Or, you can also use my fork of QuickDB (https://github.com/Androz2091/quick.db) which has a `db.init("./some_file.sqlite")` function to choose a specific file.